# Array plot not appearing on 3-D graph

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, wireframe

i have a very large structured array that i am wanting to plot as a meshgrid, but it does not appear.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


path = '/users/unsername/Desktop/untitled folder/python files/MSII_phasespace/'

os.chdir( path )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Data  
data = np.load('msii_phasespace.npy',mmap_mode='r')
    # data.size: 167197
    # data.shape: (167197,)
    # data.dtype: dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'),
      # ('velx', '<f4'), ('vely', '<f4'), ('velz', '<f4'), ('m200', '<f4')])



u = data['x']
v = data['y']
w = data['z']

Xs = np.arange(0,500, 1000)
Ys = np.arange(0,500, 1000)
Xs, Ys = np.meshgrid(Xs, Ys)
Zs = np.arange(0,500, 1000)

ax.plot(u,v,w)

ax.plot_wireframe(Xs,Ys,Zs)

plt.show()
```

I feel like that the it solely has to the with the values in my linspace, but i am not sure. Also, their is no function i can put for Zs. I want to plot all the elements that is in the array.

Also, the size, shape, and type of the array is given in #.

Comment: `Zs` also needs to be a 2D array with the same shape as `Xs` and `Ys`

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: You need an array of shape (1000,1000). What do you actually want to plot on the Z axis of your wireframe?

Comment: @tom Unfortunately, the shape of my array is (167197,). This data type has a Z component, I just want to include this array in a 3D plot. I apologize if that is vague answer.